# Rails :dependent => destroy, want to call another action instead of destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I have a has_many :through model that works perfectly.

```
  has_many :varietals
  has_many :grapes, :through => :varietals, :dependent => :destroy
```

I would like to call another action instead of :destroy. In fact, I don't want to nullify the item OR destroy it, I want to update the record status field from 1 to 0 instead of destroy the record.

How to call a custom method instead of destroy ? I suppose I can do that in the model itself... Thanks.

Where to put this method ? In the master model or in the model where the record will be destroyed ?

**EDIT**:

I'm sorry but I think I didn't enough explain my problem. My problem is not only to so something after the master model is destroyed. I want to custom the destroy action in the Varietal model itself even if the master record is not destroyed.

Something like:

```
class Varietal < ActiveRecord::Base

    private
      def destroy
        self.update_attributes(:status => 0)
      end
end
```

Actually this action is not called...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has_many :dependent is limited to only a few options. According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> :dependent If set to :destroy all the associated objects are destroyed
>   alongside this object by calling their destroy method. If set to
>   :delete_all all associated objects are deleted without calling their
>   destroy method. If set to :nullify all associated objects’ foreign
>   keys are set to NULL without calling their save callbacks. If set to
>   :restrict this object raises an ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError
>   exception and cannot be deleted if it has any associated objects.
>
> If using with the :through option, the association on the join model
>   must be a belongs_to, and the records which get deleted are the join
>   records, rather than the associated records.

It looks like you would need to alter the destroy method to update the status field.

Comment: I updated my first message and explain more... How to change the destroy method ?

Comment: Never mind if you saw my previous comment (deleted)... Phyo and Shingara have the right take.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the problem is not for associations in my model. If I have only one model, I can't overwrite the destroy method to change its behaviour. This does nothing. Adding a before or after callback won't change the destroy: the item will be destroyed.

Answer (score 12):

You can use before_destroy to put your custom logic there. E.g.,

```
before_destroy :reset_status

def reset_status
  ...
end
```

Check [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You just need add a callback on before_destroy or after_destroy and manipulate your associations. By example

```
after_destroy :do_on_grapes

def do_on_grapes
  grapes.map(&:to_do)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that good approach to solve your problem is to provide a custom destroy method. There are several responses to questions like these, but you should keep in mind that ActiveRecord and Relationships like:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

use callback mechanisms that trigger destroy chaining to your relations, too. Usually you should preserve this mechanism and add it to your custom implementation. E.g.

```
  def destroy
    self.update deleted_at: Time.now
    run_callbacks :destroy
  end
```

You can read this post, too: 
[Triggering dependent: :destroy with overridden destroy-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157987/triggering-dependent-destroy-with-overridden-destroy-method)