# Triggering dependent: :destroy with overridden destroy-method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

In our application we've overridden the ActiveRecord destroy method so that our records do not get deleted (so the user can undelete). Like so:

```
def destroy
  self.is_deleted = true
  self.save
  freeze
end
```

However, this seems to have disabled the dependent destroy on our `has_many` relationships. In other words, if `destroy` is called on a parent object, the child objects of `has_many` do not get destroyed (they don't get deleted, i.e, SQL '`DELETE...`', nor is the overridden `destroy`-method called).

How do I trigger the destruction of the child objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to trigger the destroy callback.

```
def destroy
  self.is_deleted = true
  self.save
  run_callbacks :destroy
  freeze
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was missing. :)